# How can I simplify generics usage for ports in VHDL?

Tags: generics, vhdl

Say I have an entity:

```
entity myblock is
    port(
        input1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        input2 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        input3 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        -- ...
        output : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    );
end myblock;
```

I now want to make the size of the inputs generic, so I might do:

```
entity myblock is
    generic(
        WIDTH : natural;
    );
    port(
        input1 : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        input2 : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        input3 : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        -- ...
        output : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    );
end myblock;
```

Ideally I'd like to simplify this a bit and have, say:

```
subtype calc_data is std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
port(
    input1 : calc_data;
    input2 : calc_data;
    input3 : calc_data;
    -- ...
    output : calc_data;
);
```

In this case it's a very simple example, and the benefit is not huge. In more complex cases, though, it would really help.

Is this possible in VHDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name more than one port using a single type specification:

```
entity myblock is
    generic(
        WIDTH : natural;
    );
    port(
        input1, input2, input3 : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        -- ...
        output : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    );
end myblock;
```

Comment: Huh, I had forgotten about that. That's a help.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 (a generic) is often used when the inputs are just going to be vectors

If your subtype is used to carry "meaning-to-the-reader" (rather than just "width-information" ), then store the subtype in a package.

Another alternative is to use `std_logic_vector` without width specification and have the width propagate down from the higher level.

(There is a proposal for a new iteration of VHDL for [anonymous types](http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/AnonymousTypes), which you might find interesting)

Comment: How can the subtype in a package be generic?

Comment: Normally subtypes-with-meaning are not generic - so you have `subtype address_bus : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);`. With VHDL 2008 you *can* have generics on the package and propagate those to the types

Comment: Hmm. If I have a subtype-with-meaning, I can't have different values for different instances of the entity, but I think that's what you're saying here, right? (Also, I don't think Xilinx' toolchain supports 2008 stuff yet, which is what I'm using.)

Comment: Yes, one subtype per entity definition, so you can't change it per instance :(